# What is the hyphen (‐) used for in this command tee <<-'EOF'?

Tags: here-document

I saw the following command:

```
sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json <<-'EOF'
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://xxxxxxxx.mirror.aliyuncs.com"]
}
EOF
```

What is the hyphen (‐) used for? It works fine even i remove the hyphen.

Comment: It will cause it to strip leading **tabs** (and only tabs, not spaces!) from each line from the here-document, and also recognize the delimiter (EOF) if preceded by tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hyphen/dash is used for telling the shell to remove any leading tab character from the here-document.  This is documented [by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) as part of the here-document redirection:

> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, all leading `<tab>` characters shall be stripped from input lines and the line containing the trailing delimiter. [...]

The feature allows for creating slightly prettier scripts:

```sh
while some-condition; do

    some-command <<-END_INPUT
    some data
    goes here
    END_INPUT

done
```

(where each line in the here-document and the line containing the `END_INPUT` delimiter are indented using tabs), as opposed to

```sh
while some-condition; do

    some-command <<END_INPUT
some data
goes here
END_INPUT

done
```